# Is there any canonical evidence of Vulcan nerve pinch being used on species other than humans, humanoids and horses?

Tags: star-trek

The [Vulcan nerve pinch clearly works on humans and other humanoids](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgMjV3Yse3U). And—as seen in the 1989 film, [*Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYezfpJvFsw)—it can clearly work on horses as well.

Is there any ***canonical*** evidence of the Vulcan nerve pinch being used on other non-human/non-humanoid species, wild animals, or even on small domesticated animals like cats or dogs?

Comment: Please note that this question was previously asked by @JakeGould who asked for it to be deleted. I've reposted it.

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Richard, I thought you understood that we don't mention Star Trek V around here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Vulcan Nerve pinch seems to be effective on a wide range of humanoid species (Human, other Vulcans, Romulans, etc) as well as certain animal species, notably a horse in the Star Trek V film.

Spock knocks out a giant [panther-like creature](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Sa-te_kru) in the "When Worlds Collide" [webcomic](http://archive.wired.com/special_multimedia/2009/whenWorldsCollide). Interestingly, because it's a Robert Orci creation, it's actually a higher canon level than the animated series (see below)

[image]

---

As far as other animals are concerned, we see the Nerve Pinch being used against an alien creature known as a [Le-Matya](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Le-matya) in the Star Trek animated series.

[image]

**For the record, I'm unaware of the Nerve Pinch ever being used on anything as small as a cat or a dog but there's certainly no reason to assume that it *wouldn't* work.**

Comment: Isn't the "giant panther-like creature" in the top image called a Sehlat?

Comment: @Omegacron - The text calls it a "Sa-te Kru Cat"

Comment: @Richard - yep, just looked up Sehlats and they have a panther-like body but the head is more like a bear. Oops, I feel so ashamed.